# What is the best way to unescape a string which escape by JavaScript escape function?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I am passing a comment to a web service using AJAX call. I want to unescape that string at server side (VB.NET). I found 2 options for that.

```
System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(myComment)
```

and

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(myComment)
```

I want to know the best way to do it.

Comment: [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

Comment: Use `UrlDecode`, thats what its for. `UnescapeDataString` will not convert `+` to space for example.  (If your using ASP.Net the request collections will contain unescaped query data)

Comment: Thanks @AlexK. But I am using this to get user's comment. So I have to get each character he entered.

Comment: Wouldn't JSON be a better fit? Or posting that data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` from a form?